# XCodebuild not running tests on Simulator

Tags: ios, xcode7, xcodebuild

I am running the following command from command line to build/test my workspace. The idea is to port it eventually to a CI system. But what happens is that one of the runs succeed but all of the following ones fail. They fail in an odd manner in that the build completes as part of the command but then, I see the message which kicks off the simulator and I see the simulator up but the tests are never run on it. The command is either hung on it forever or it fails with no error message. I tried using `xcrun simctl erase all` before the command to make sure the simulator is clean. I also tried avoiding specifying `derivedDatapath` and `OBJROOT` hoping that would make the builds clean but so far, I am stuck here.

```
xcodebuild test  -workspace <workspace-name> -scheme <scheme-name> -configuration Coverage -sdk iphonesimulator -destination platform='iOS Simulator',OS=9.0,name='iPhone 6'
```

The final error I see is `/usr/bin/touch -c /home-folder/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/.../Build/Products/Coverage-iphonesimulator/Tests.xctest    ** TEST FAILED **`

The code runs smoothly from within XCode and the tests always pass. I believe this is some issue with the terminal app connecting to the simulator or the simulator being in a weird state after an earlier run but I could not figure out what could be causing the problem. Any suggestions would be great.

XCode Version: 7.0.1

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if that is the issue, but shouldn't `test` be at the end of the line? Like this:

```
xcodebuild -workspace <workspace-name> -scheme <scheme-name> -configuration Coverage -sdk iphonesimulator -destination platform='iOS Simulator',OS=9.0,name='iPhone 6' test
```

Comment: I did try it but it dint help. So, I dont think it makes any difference.